# Select dates older than time frame SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find all records in a database with an admission date which is older than a certain time frame (in this case, all admission dates older than 4 days old).

I have:

```
     select memberid, admitdate
     from membertable
     where admitdate < (sysdate-4)
```

As a result, I'm getting a lot of admission dates which match this, but I'm ALSO getting dates which are from only 2 days ago, so that doesn't match my code.  What am I doing wrong?

If it helps, the admit dates have a format of mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: What a data type is the `admitdate` column? Dates don't have any intrinsic format, so hopefully it is actually a date column you're just seeing displayed like that, not a string (varchar2) column. If it is a date can you give an example from `select to_char(admitdate, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from membertable where admitdate < sysdate-4` that you don't expect to see? (The two options I can see are that you're seeing values from 3 days ago not 2, and just need to `trunc(sysdate)` in the comparison; or you have values that are BCE instead of CE, which will show as negative...)

Comment: Hello! The column admitdate is a "date" data type.  Perhaps there's formatting going on using the editor I'm using (Toad) that makes the dates as mm/dd/yyyy?  Either way, using where admitdate < trunc(sysdate)-4 seems to be working and providing values which are more in line with what I expect.  When I use your portion "to_char(admitdate, 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", that returns admitdate as 2018-06-17 00:00:00.

Comment: Yes, your client will format the date as a string for you. I can't remember if Toad uses its own settings or NLS, but it doesn't matter. Is showing the dates with the S format shows them all as positive then it sounds like it's just the trunc that's needed. You shouldn't see the 17th when applying your filter though, only up to 23:59:29 on the 16th (assuming your system date is the 21st).

Answer (score 1):

Dates, including sysdate, have a time component. Even if all your `admitdate` values are at midnight that is still a time, and sysdate is only going to be at midnight if you run your query then.

```
select sysdate, sysdate-4, trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate)-4 from dual;

SYSDATE             SYSDATE-4           TRUNC(SYSDATE)      TRUNC(SYSDATE)-4   
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2018-06-21 16:44:53 2018-06-17 16:44:53 2018-06-21 00:00:00 2018-06-17 00:00:00
```

If you filter your records on `sysdate-4` then that will include any `admitdate` values up to, in this example, 2018-06-17 16:44:53; so presumably all the records for the 17th if they are actually all midnight.

```
with membertable (memberid, admitdate) as (
            select 1, date '2018-06-15' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2018-06-16' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2018-06-17' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2018-06-18' from dual
  union all select 5, date '2018-06-19' from dual
  union all select 6, date '2018-06-20' from dual
  union all select 7, date '2018-06-21' from dual
)
select memberid, admitdate
from membertable
where admitdate < (sysdate-4);

  MEMBERID ADMITDATE          
---------- -------------------
         1 2018-06-15 00:00:00
         2 2018-06-16 00:00:00
         3 2018-06-17 00:00:00
```

If you truncate the value you're comparing against then its time portion will also be treated as midnight, so you'll only match record up to - but not including - that point in time, 2018-06-17 00:00:00:

```
with membertable (memberid, admitdate) as (
            select 1, date '2018-06-15' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2018-06-16' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2018-06-17' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2018-06-18' from dual
  union all select 5, date '2018-06-19' from dual
  union all select 6, date '2018-06-20' from dual
  union all select 7, date '2018-06-21' from dual
)
select memberid, admitdate
from membertable
where admitdate < trunc(sysdate)-4;

  MEMBERID ADMITDATE          
---------- -------------------
         1 2018-06-15 00:00:00
         2 2018-06-16 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`admitdate` should be a `date`.  You seem to be suggesting it is a string.  You can try:

```
where to_date(admitdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < trunc(sysdate) - 4;
```

You can then fix the data in the table, so it is stored as a date.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the format of the table or the columns.  The column "admitdate" is listed as a data type of "date". When I try your suggestion, I get an error that "it is not a valid month".

Comment: NK369, you're in a contradiction. If ADMITDATE is really a DATE (datatype), then your query (`where admitdate < trunc(sysdate) - 4`) should work. If it is a VARCHAR2 column and contains values in MM/DD/YYYY format, then TO_DATE fails when it finds e.g. 23/15/2018 (because there's no 23rd month). So, what is ADMITDATE, really? Post table description and some sample data. Also, saying that values are stored in MM/DD/YYYY format - if the column's datatype is DATE, then your system's default date format is MM/DD/YYYY. Oracle stores dates in a format not readable by humans.